# Did I flood my septic system?

Tags: septic

New leach pit was put in 4 months ago. The system hasn’t been used at all since then due to renovation. Yesterday however, one of the faucets was accidentally left on for about 16 hours at full blast.

Given the system hadn’t been used at all for 4 months I wonder has this caused permanent damage to the system? BTW, we’re not planning to use it again for the next 10 days or so.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If the answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem at all! If there is a bunch of water it will at best wash all the debris down the system. As far as a problem NO WAY! 
You may be able to over fill a system with water but once the flow is reduced it will recover and there will be NO damage. 
I have installed many systems, the only one ones that failed took years when met code. 
Yes you can cause problems with a full flow of water but after a day or so everything will be fine if your system passed perc testing or whatever your state requires.

Comment: Thank you! Yes we did a perk test and met the requirements for local code just 4 months ago. As I said it hasn’t been used at all in the past four months and the next two weeks will see almost no use again. I have just heard stories about how even a leaking toilet can ruin a septic system by introducing too much water into the biome and killing the balance. Glad to hear your input though. Thank you!!